# HTML Email Not Generating Links (A tags) in Outlook

Tags: email, outlook, html-email

In checking an email that I am coding (a reply-type email that my server will send), I notice that the `a` tag hyperlinks in my code are not working in Outlook. They work elsewhere, but not Outlook.

I know very little about Microsoft products, but I can tell you that the place I'm seeing this is in the online outlook.com you view in a web browser.

The simplest link, such as this...

`<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Click here</a>`

...is coming through like this in the rendered email:

`[http:www.yahoo.com]Click here`

AND, it is not a link. It's just text. It appears as though the program is disabling the links (possibly because it finds the email suspicious of phishing, even though I added the domain to my trusted emails)???

Anyone know what is happening or how I can work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the code you've posted, but I do know that Outlook.com will do this to links when it doesn't recognize them as valid links to an external site. Look for hidden characters, "smart" quotes instead of plain quotes, etc. in the link.

Comment: That was it. Outlook adding this to a link that it found a problem with, and there was a character issue in my original item that was tripping it up. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You should put the target on the link.

Like this:

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank">Click here</a>
```